# Call different Fragment function in Activity in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments

The code is in the Android Studio template.

Android Studio - Create new project - Navigation Drawer Activity

There are an Activity and three Fragments (HomeFragment, GalleryFragment, SlideshowFragment) in the template project. I use an AppBarConfiguration object to manage three Fragment. Now I create a function in each Fragment.

My title may be a bit vague. My problem is how to execute the method in the current fragment by clicking the button in Activity.

Now my solution is as follows.

In each fragment. Get the activity object and find the button. Then set the click method. Here is my Kotlin code.

```
activity?.findViewById<FloatingActionButton>(R.id.fab)?.setOnClickListener { view ->
    myFunction()
}
```

It works fine. But I think this is not elegant enough. And there are some problems with this. If I only set the click event of one fragment, when I switch to another fragment, the click event just now will be executed after I click the button.
I guess the reason for the above problem is that the click event of the activity is bound by the fragment.

My other solution is as follows.

Create an ActivityViewModel and set a LiveData value. Change value after clicking the button. Get ActivityViewModel in fragment and observe the value in each fragment. Then execute the method when the value is changed

My third solution is as follows.

Get each fragment object and determine whether it is visible. Then perform the function of the visible fragment. Here is my Kotlin code.

```
val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
var fragment1 = navHostFragment!!.childFragmentManager.fragments[0] as HomeFragment

var fragment2 = navHostFragment!!.childFragmentManager.fragments[1] as GalleryFragment

var fragment3 = navHostFragment!!.childFragmentManager.fragments[2] as SlideshowFragment

if(fragment1.isVisiable){
    fragment1.myFunction()
}else if(fragment2.isVisiable){
    fragment2.myFunction()
}else if(fragment3.isVisiable){
    fragment3.myFunction()
}
```

But I still think the methods above are not elegant enough.

Can I use the interface to achieve the above functions? And how to achieve it?

I am not a native English speaker. Sorry for my bad English.

Thanks.

Comment: i don't understand _why_ you would want to do any of this. why are you setting a click listener to a button (for your activity) from your fragment ? why not just have the button part of your fragment ?

Comment: @a_local_nobody. The code is Android tamplate demo. I want to move the button position when long press. If the button is in the part of fragment. Then the button position will be different in different fragment. Maintenance is troublesome.